Inconsistent Sourcery Output for Protocols with Associated Types
I use Sourcery in my iOS project  to generate mocks for a protocol that conforms to another protocol with associated types. Despite consistent input, the generated output from Sourcery is not consistent. Sometimes the output is correct, but other times it's incorrect, defining Mock as a class with only init.
Here is my AutoMockable.stencil: https://gist.github.com/levan9999/212647d48ef372e025d5794543ab303c
Here’s my setup:
public protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Input
    associatedtype Output
    associatedtype Failure: Error

    @discardableResult
    func bar(parameters: Input) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure>
}

// sourcery: AutoMockable
public protocol Bar: Foo
where Input == String,
      Output == Bool,
      Failure == Never { }

Output:
public class Bar: Foo {
    public init() {}
}

How can I ensure Sourcery consistently generates the correct mock for protocols with associated types and type constraints?
